# How do I find Sxx in a Simple linear regression model?

Tags: statistics, regression, regression-analysis

In a Simple linear regression model, I have only Sxy and Syy data with me. How shall I derive Sxx, linking Sxy and Syy based on first principles? I know the formulas separately. I want to find Sxx, given only Sxy and Syy.

Comment: Are you sure you have no other information? Sample size? Correlation coefficient? Gradient of line of best fit?

Comment: I know the way, if additional data is provided. I wanted to know how to derive given only this data. The additional data is- --- > "He computes the average rainfall (y) recorded in his city on each calendar day (x) during the month of September over the last 10 years." I can do it the other way. Taking sigma x^2 - n . x-bar ^2  and then, I can use, [n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 - n(n(n+1)/2n)^2] considering x takes the values 1,2,3,....30. So, n=30. But, in key, they have written in brackets - Sxx can be derived from first principles. So, is it possible to derive from Sxy and Syy data without this info?

Comment: It is not possible to do what you want to do.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for clarification.